# Darken image overlay and add text over it in CSS

Tags: html, css, overlay, transparency

How would I darken (add a semi-transparent overlay) and add text to this image (but centred horizontally and vertically) as below:

[image]

**HTML**

```html
<img src="http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg" id="top" data-appear-animation="fadeIn">
```

**CSS**

```css
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6jf0nxd5/

Comment: See my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/27149113/104380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the text horizontaly and verticaly, you will need to wrap it in a container with `text-align:center;`. Then you can use a pseudo element to center it verticaly. For the overlay, you can give the text container a `rgba()` background color that can have transparency :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6jf0nxd5/19/)**

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
.wrap{
    position:relative;
}
.wrap img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
.text{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    text-align:center;
}
.text:after{
    content:'';
    width:1px; height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}
.text span{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg" id="top" data-appear-animation="fadeIn" />
    <div class="text"><span>Text over the image
        <br/>Second line</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

*HTML :*

```html
<img src="http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg" id="top" data-appear-animation="fadeIn">
<div class="sometext">some text</div>
```

*CSS :*

```css
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity:.3;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.sometext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

You can use the `filter` property with the `brightness` value:

```css
.imgWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.imgWrap > img{
  filter: brightness(0.4);
}

.imgWrap > span{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  font: 22px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class='imgWrap'>
  <span>This is some very long text that might or might now flow on top of the image</span>
  <img src="http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg">
</div>
```

### Method 2:

You can wrap the image and text in a wrapper element with a black background, and set an `opacity` for the image so more of the black background will be visible:

```css
.imgWrap {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.imgWrap > img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .5;
}

.imgWrap > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.imgWrap>span::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='imgWrap'>
  <span>This is some very long text that might or might now flow on top of the image</span>
  <img src="http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```html
<div id='back'><div id='mask'><div id='text'>fsfsfsssf</div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://luxurylaunches.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/uber-london.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
#mask {
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%; 
  height: 500px; 
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  left: 48%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jf0nxd5/20/